# Angular 8 and Bootstrap 4 Tooltips

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm triying to impletement tooltips from bootstrap 4 in my webapp, according to bootstrap documentation i should initialize the tooltips with this code

> `$(function () { $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() })` (Done in `app.component.ts`)

Also in `angular.json` should put `popper.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`(Done)

Obviously i already had installed npm bootstrap and jquery, and reading in another post they do two imports in `app.component.ts`

> `import 'bootstrap' and import * as $ from 'jquery'`;

And they also add `AfterViewChecked` in the implements of AppComponent class precisely for the initialization like

`ngAfterViewChecked(){ $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();}`

When i do all of this the tooltips actually works, but, the `import 'bootstrap'` generate some problem with the rest of bootstrap.js because my li tag dropdown stop working. Can somebody help me? Thx!

Answer (score -3):

Instead of jQuery, I suggest you to use **Angular Bootstrap** libraries like:

- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home
- https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/

They will make your job easier and you don't have to add jQuery.

**About the tooltip:**

1 - Install Ngx Bootstrap

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap
```

2 - Add TooltipModule to your AppModule

```
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

3 - Use tooltip functionality

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tooltip="Lorem ipsum.">
  Simple demo
</button>
```

You can find more information here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip .